# Ways of recovering a missing .bash_history due to a 100% full disk?

Tags: bash, disk-space, ssh-tunnel

Two Putty sessions were opened to a Debian 6 Linux. Log-files led to a full disk. The bash history of the entire shell sessions is missing, and even beyond that (This may be due to a blocked writing-mode, with the last blocks being cut off)

- Is there a way of recovery or a duplicate history file?
- Do you have a cron-job running that regularly backups your bash-history?

Comment: Its sessions ended then the history is gone.

Comment: Unlucky, lost my bash history, too bad :(

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have set up a backup yourself I think you're out of luck. I doubt any distros use default settings which back up the history, but without inspecting your system in detail it would be impossible to say for sure.

*If the sessions are still running*, however, you could try running the `history` command. I'm pretty sure it simply reads from `~/.bash_history`, but maybe it stores that in memory until the next command?

You could also copy the shell output to a file, and `grep` that to at least recover the last few commands.

Regarding backup, I've personally found that GitHub is a great place for [.bash_history](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.bash_history). A little excessive for most people, perhaps, but it keeps the common commands always at the ready.

Comment: Bash history entries are committed to disk only every so often by default; if you haven't yet closed the session(s) you're interested in, and assuming you haven't done `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` or something equally atrocious, then doing `history` may well get you at least the last hundred or so lines of what would've gone into ~/.bash_history. Can't hurt to try, again assuming the shell or shells in question haven't yet been killed; if they have, I'm afraid you're SOL.

Comment: Also, +1 for the perversity of putting `.bash_history` under VC...

Comment: @AaronMiller afaikt, it is a command summary. So no curl oAuth tokens and other 'sensitive material'. And yes the session was killed unfortunately.

Comment: @LoSauer Oh, I'm not saying it's a security risk particularly, at least not for anyone who washes his hands after going to the toilet and doesn't include passwords in his command lines -- just that the idea of putting a state file like that under version control strikes me as a bit perverse. (Not that I wouldn't consider doing it, under circumstances which made it useful.)

Comment: @AaronMiller Two things which ensure no sensitive material: Every line is reviewed before committing (to generalize and add tags), and `HISTCONTROL` contains `ignorespace`.